# multer storing the destination as temp rather than in server

Tags: node.js, forms, express, multer

*./routes/index.js*

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
middleware = require('./middleware');
importRoutes = keystone.importer(__dirname);
User = keystone.list('User');
multer = require('multer');

keystone.pre('routes', middleware.initLocals);
keystone.pre('render', middleware.flashMessages);

var routes = {
    views: importRoutes('./views'),
};

exports = module.exports = function (app) {
    //multer uplaoding to local destination
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(req);
            cb(null, '../public/images')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {        
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
        }
    });

    const upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('profilePic');
    // Views
    app.get('/', middleware.requireUser, routes.views.index);
    app.get('/blog/:category?', routes.views.blog);
    app.get('/blog/post/:post', routes.views.post);
    app.get('/gallery', routes.views.gallery);
    app.get('/research', routes.views.research);
    app.get('/publications', routes.views.publications);
    app.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
        res.render('profile.hbs');
    });
    app.get('/teaching-initiatives', routes.views.teaching);
    app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
        var updatedFirst = req.body.first_name;
        var updatedLast = req.body.last_name;

        if (updatedFirst != '' && updatedLast != '') {
            req.user.name.first = updatedFirst;
            req.user.name.last = updatedLast;
        }
        // console.log(req.user.name.first);
        req.user.save(function (saveError) {
            if (saveError) {
                console.log(saveError);
            }
        });

        upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.render('profile', {
                    msg : err
                });
            } else {            
                console.log(req);
                res.redirect('/profile');
                //res.send('test');
            }
        })
    });
    app.all('/contact', routes.views.contact);
};
```

*./templates/views/public.hbs*

```
<div class="container-fluid profile">
<div class="row">

    <form action="/upload" method="post" class="col s12 m12 l12 z-depth-2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" class="validate" data-length="15">
                <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" class="validate" data-length="15">
                <label for="last_name" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Last Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>     
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Update<i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
        <div class="file-field input-field">
            <div class="btn grey">
                <span>Profile Pic</span>
                <input name="profilePic" type="file" >
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                <input class="file-path validate"  type="text">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn">Upload <i class="material-icons right">file_upload</i></button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

I have tested this in another project with basic express structure. It is working perfectly. But here it is taking destination as mentioned rather going to a temp folder on the local system.

I have checked `enctype='multipart/form-data'` & `fieldname` too. But I am not getting what is going wrong. Is it the requests?

Comment: Where is your `/upload` path defined? You have `/update`?

Comment: I updated that! Please check now

Comment: "[...] here it is taking destination" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Destination is the place where file has to be uploaded.

Comment: I am still confused by your question. Do you mean that the upload is storing the file in `../public/images` instead of the temp folder you mentioned? What is the path of this "temp" folder?

Comment: It is supposed to store in ``` ../public /images``` but it is going to local(my system) temp folder

Comment: Are the files storing as the correct filename? You also mention that you managed to get this working with a separate bare-bones express app. What is different of that one and is it possible to post your code?

Comment: Nope! Name is assigned as random. And the only difference is that exports. I am not even getting what to console to find the bug.

Comment: I am unsure why you are using the additional `exports` here. You are using 2 methods of ES5 exports. Why?